# Stored Procedure Not Executing ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I really don't know what to do. Could you please help me?

What I'm trying to do is that when a person watns to modify his data shown at screen taken from the DataBase when they finish modifing they click in a button and that's where the stored procedure comes in a checks if the data was modified it updates but if it isn't modified...well it doesn't modify the DataBase BUT when i run the proyect it just doesn't work.

The funny thing is that the Stored Procedure works at SQLServer but at C# won't.

Here's my code:

Stored Procedure:

```
    Create Procedure SP_PDF
    (@nombre varchar(50), @tel int, @dir varchar(50), @rfc char(13))
    as
    declare @cont int
    set @cont = 0
    while(@cont < 4)
    Begin
        if((select nombre from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @nombre)
            Begin
                update cat_cliente set nombre = @nombre 
            End
        else
            Begin
                set @cont += 1
            End 
        if((select telefono from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @tel)
            Begin
                update cat_cliente set telefono = @tel
            End
        else
            Begin
                set @cont += 1
            End
        if((select direccion from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @dir)
            Begin
                update cat_cliente set direccion = @dir
            End
        else
            Begin
                set @cont += 1
            End
    End
```

C#:

```
        String query = "exec SP_PDF @nombre, @tel, @dir, @rfc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Nombre.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Telefono.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Direccion.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", SqlDbType.Char).Value = RFC.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet set = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adp.Fill(set);
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('¡Funciono!');</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnx.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting

Comment: `it just doesn't work`!!! try to debug and find any exceptions.

Comment: If you put a break point in your `catch`, does it get hit?  If so, what is the exception?

Comment: since you are already passing parameters with Parameters.AddWithValue adding the same in string query is not necessary

Comment: "Could not find stored procedure 'exec SP_PDF'."

That's the exception that throws.

Comment: BTW...thanks a lot for your help. You are really amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Try This Alter your SP as below

```
ALTER Procedure SP_PDF
(@nombre varchar(50), @tel int, @dir varchar(50), @rfc char(13))
as
declare @cont int
set @cont = 0


declare @sp_nombre varchar(50) 
declare @sp_tel int
declare @sp_dir varchar(50)
declare @sp_rfc char(13)

select @sp_nombre=nombre,@sp_tel=telefono,@sp_dir=direccion from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc

while(@cont < 4)
Begin
    if( @sp_nombre <> @nombre)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set nombre = @nombre 
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End 
    if(@sp_tel <> @tel)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set telefono = @tel
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End
    if(@sp_dir <> @dir)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set direccion = @dir
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End
End
```

Write C# code as below

```
  String query = "SP_PDF";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Nombre.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Telefono.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Direccion.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", SqlDbType.Char).Value = RFC.Text;
        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('¡Funciono!');</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnx.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Well...now it runs BUT it doesn´t update the information if I modify it. I think it is my Stored Procedure but I can't  error, it runs at Sql Server and that is what doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: It's up there at the description of my question.

Comment: I have updated the above code please try the code it will work for you

Comment: If you modify store procedure then again execute

Comment: I have modified SP and C# code please use above code it will works for you i think.First execute sp in SQL server and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify like the following

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cnx;
    cmd.Text = "SP_PDF";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Nombre.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Telefono.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Direccion.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", SqlDbType.Char).Value = RFC.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet set = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = cnx;
        cnx.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        adp.Fill(set);
        Response.Write("<script>window.alert('¡Funciono!');</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cnx.Close();
    }
```

Comment: help the OP to understand what changes you have made and how?

Comment: "Could not find stored procedure 'exec SP_PDF'." 
That's the exception that is still throwing.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify store procedure then again execute

```
ALTER Procedure SP_PDF
(@nombre varchar(50), @tel int, @dir varchar(50), @rfc char(13))
as
declare @cont int
set @cont = 0
while(@cont < 4)
Begin
    if((select nombre from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @nombre)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set nombre = @nombre 
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End 
    if((select telefono from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @tel)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set telefono = @tel
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End
    if((select direccion from cat_cliente where rfc = @rfc) != @dir)
        Begin
            update cat_cliente set direccion = @dir
        End
    else
        Begin
            set @cont += 1
        End
End
```

and then execute the code again.

Comment: I think that my C# code it's executing the SP because it never receives the command to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that it's funny thing is that SP working in sql server and not in c#. B'coz there is some mistake in your code.

```
String query = "SP_PDF";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Nombre.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Telefono.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Direccion.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", SqlDbType.Char).Value = RFC.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet set = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        cnx.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        adp.Fill(set);
        Response.Write("<script>window.alert('¡Funciono!');</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cnx.Close();
    }
```

OR

Go to this site :- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-Update-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures-using-ADO.Net.aspx